# Showing percent in label

Tags: ios, objective-c, label

I use code for showing the progress of downloading a file from 1% to 100%.

```
if( downloadTask == _downloadTask26){


        _progress26 = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalBytesWritten] floatValue];
        _total26 = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalBytesExpectedToWrite] floatValue];

    }

    if( downloadTask == _downloadTask27){


        _progress27 = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalBytesWritten] floatValue];
        _total27 = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalBytesExpectedToWrite] floatValue];

    }

        float progress = _progress26 + _progress27;
        float total = _total26 + _total27;

        NSString *percentage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f%%", ((progress / total) * 100)];
        (NSLog (percentage, @"%.f%%"));
        if (!_label3) {

                _label3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200.43, 158.84, 42, 19)];

                _label3.numberOfLines = 1;
                _label3.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines;
                _label3.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
                _label3.minimumScaleFactor = 10.0f/12.0f;
                _label3.clipsToBounds = YES;
                _label3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                _label3.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                _label3.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

                [_scroller addSubview:_label3];
            }
        }

        _label3.text = percentage;
        if ([_label3.text  isEqual: @"100%"]) {
        }
```

But when file downloading, percent is not displayed in ascending order. Percent is displayed in a different order like in the video below. How do I fix it?

video 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0EJbcHq3ZALUVRzanJ6SndscWc/view

Answer (score 0):

May be it's due to downloading task condition which check it is downloadingTask26 or 27 put logs inside this two conditions and check downloaded and total size . Total task may be changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you simplified the code in your question, where the code generating the video has more that just downloads 26 and 27 included? With only two downloads, I'd expect it to drop down only once, but if you have many downloads, I'd expect it to drop down each time a new download start.

Bottom line, if you really have many downloads, the result makes perfect sense because it's quite likely that you don't have values for total bytes for many of the downloads until they actually start and when a later download starts, suddenly the sum of total bytes downloaded will increase (and thus the percentage will drop).

One solution is to use `NSProgress`, create a child `NSProgress` for each download up front and then update the percentage for parent progress. That way, downloads that haven't started yet will be reflected in the total percentage.

Comment: Yes I  simplified the code because it very large. Can you show how to add correctly NSProgress in my code?

Comment: See the excellent WWDC 2015 video [Best Practices for Progress Reporting](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/232/).